# Bash functions inside process substitution

Tags: bash

Getting an error trying to call a function inside a process substitution.
Is there any way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
function testfunc 
{
   echo "bork"
}

diff <(testfunc) <(echo "bork")
```

The error is:

```
bork.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bork.sh: line 7: `diff <(testfunc) <(echo "bork")'
```

--Update--
Problem was calling sh bork.sh, instead of bash ./bork.sh . Moral of the story make sure which shell you are executing with.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Did you run `sh script`?  Using `function` is not POSIX standard — it's generally better to use `testfunc() { echo "bork"; }` (where the semicolon is necessary when the `}` is on the same line as `"bork"`, but not otherwise).

Comment: What error? In what version of bash? I don't see any error when I run this script with bash 3.2.57(1) shipped with OS X 10.11.

Comment: _"Getting an error..."_   The purpose of the shell giving us error _messages_ is for us to _read_ them.  Tell us exactly what the error message was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem here:

```
$ chmod  +x test.sh 
$ ./test.sh
```

Clear diff. No problem!

```
$ bash -x ./test.sh 
+ diff /dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62
++ testfunc
++ echo bork
++ echo bork
```

Proof that it worked

### Troubleshooting:

Maybe you

- run in a restricted shell
- you don't have `/dev/fd` available/mounted correctly (due to somekind of secure chroot jail?)

Comment: Added some trouble shooting hints

Comment: That was the problem, bash ./foo.sh worked; sh foo.sh didn't.

Comment: :headdesk: Glad it helped though :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably that you're running the command with `sh` instead of `bash`.

```
$ cat > xx.sh
#!/bin/bash
function testfunc 
{
   echo "bork"
}

diff <(testfunc) <(echo "bork")
$ sh xx.sh
xx.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
xx.sh: line 7: `diff <(testfunc) <(echo "bork")'
$ bash xx.sh
$
```

The process substitution is not portable to the shell in `/bin/sh`.  See the Bash manual on [POSIX mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode) and bullet 28:

> 28. Process substitution is not available.

Tested on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite).